# TypeError: Cannot set property 'header' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a website in which there is option to select color to have a custom theme of chat box. Whenever I select a color from color picker I encounter this error. for example if I want to change color of header of chat box whenever I select color below error occur:

[image]

I am just sharing the part of code if there would be need of showing more code I will update it later.

*ThemeChanger.js*

```
class ThemeChanger extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {
      header,
      pane,
      body,
      composer,
      textarea,
      button,
      messageBackgroundImage,
    } = this.props.customThemeValue;
    const showMessageBackgroundImage = messageBackgroundImage !== '';
    this.state = {
      header,
      pane,
      body,
      composer,
      textarea,
      button,
      backgroundImage: '',
      messageBackgroundImage,
      showMessageBackgroundImage,
    };

    this.initialValue = {
      header,
      pane,
      body,
      composer,
      textarea,
      button,
      backgroundImage: '',
      messageBackgroundImage,
      showMessageBackgroundImage,
    };
  }

  handleChangeMessageBackgroundImage = name => e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  // get the selected custom colour
  handleChangeComplete = (name, color) => {
    if (color) {
      this.setState({ currTheme: 'custom' });
      if (!color.startsWith('#')) {
        color = '#' + color;
      }
      // Send these Settings to Server
      let state = this.state;

      if (name === 'header') {
        state.header = color;
        this.customTheme.header = state.header.substring(1);
}
      this.setState(state);
      document.body.style.setProperty('background-color',this.state.body);
    }
  };
```

*ColorPickerComponent/index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ColorPicker from 'material-ui-color-picker';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './ColorPicker.css';

const ColorBox = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #0000006e;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 0.625rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  background-color: ${props => props.backgroundColor};
`;

const ColorPickerContainer = styled.div`
  margin-left: 2.8rem;
  margin-top: -1.8rem;
  width: 6rem;
`;

const ColorPickerComponent = props => {
  const {
    backgroundColor,
    handleClickColorBox,
    id,
    handleChangeColor,
    component,
  } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <ColorBox
        backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
        onClick={() => handleClickColorBox(id)}
      />
      <ColorPickerContainer>
        <ColorPicker
          name="color"
          id={'colorPicker' + id}
          defaultValue={backgroundColor}
          onChange={color => handleChangeColor(component, color)}
        />
      </ColorPickerContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I hope I am able to explain please help if needed I can share more details about this. Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: You don't have customTheme defined in this class.

Answer (score 0):

When you destructure your props into objects here:

```
 const {
  header,
  pane,
  body,
  composer,
  textarea,
  button,
  messageBackgroundImage,
} = this.props.customThemeValue;
```

You save your header in a constant called header, then you use that const to create a `header` key in your state object.

Down here, you access a class property that does not exist, `customTheme`:

```
if (name === 'header') { 
   state.header = color; 
   this.customTheme.header = state.header.substring(1);
}
```

Are you trying to update the header in the state here? If yes, then you should do:

```
this.setState({header: color});
```

Supposedly, that would update the header wherever you're using it.

What is `customTheme` supposed to be here?